# Get session variable directly in component HTML within Angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, session-variables

Is there a way to get and display the the value of session variable directly in component HTML without assigning a local variable with the value of session variable ?

Something like:

```
<span>{{sessionStorage.getItem('name')}}</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context), the expression context in the template is the component instance. Since [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is a member of the `window` object, you cannot refer to it directly in the template:

> Template expressions cannot refer to anything in the global namespace,
>   except `undefined`. They can't refer to `window` or `document`.

---

You can make `sessionStorage` available in the template by assigning it to a public property of the component class:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  public sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
}
```

and refer to that property in the template:

```html
<span>{{sessionStorage.getItem('name')}}</span>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6m952g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: That would work, what I would like to do is get the session value without need to declare local variables/objects in the component

Comment: I added more details to my answer.